# How to make a custom google sign-in button for dark mode?

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, google-oauth, google-signin

I am trying to integrate the google default sign-in button into my website though it is working fine, I am seeing annoying white space, how to eliminate that?

**Image:**
[Google sign-in button in black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKFKj.png)

```
import useScript from "../hooks/useScript";
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";
import Router from "next/router";
import { useRef } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function GoogleLogin(props) {
    const googleSignInButton = useRef(null);
    const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme();

    const onGoogleSignIn = async (data) => {
        const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5555/api/auth/v1/google", data);
        console.log(res.data.url);
    }

    useScript("https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client", () => {
        window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GAUTH_CLIENT,
            allowed_parent_origin: "http://localhost:3000",
            callback: onGoogleSignIn,
            auto_select: true,
            context: 'use'
        });
        window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            googleSignInButton.current,
            {
                // type: "icon",
                size: "large",
                text: "continue_with",
                theme: "filled_black",
            });
        google.accounts.id.prompt();
    });

    return <div ref={googleSignInButton}></div>;
}
```

**My tries:**

- I tried styling this button using sass, but apparently, the main button is inside the iframe which I can't not style.
- I tried developing a custom button using google GSI APIs, but it's deprecated and doesn't work with new Oauth creditents.
- I tried making a custom button that invokes google login on click but it also didn't work.

Right now, I understand that the new google sign-in does give much freedom to customize, Is there is way around it?

Comment: I haven't played with it much yet, but [@react-oauth/google](https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth) seems to have facilities for customizing the login button. [Demo](https://react-oauth.vercel.app/)

Answer (score 2):

Add `color-scheme: light;` to button wrapper

Comment: Which button wrapper, specifically? the iframe, or the parent of the iframe?

Comment: It does not matter

Answer (score 0):

```
<GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={GOOGLE_APP_ID}>
        <div style={{colorScheme: 'light'}}>
            <GoogleLogin 
                text="signin_with"
                size="medium"
                onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                theme='filled_black'
                shape='circle'
            />
        </div>
</GoogleOAuthProvider>
```

Here you go an example